# Running a Python model

Tags: python

I've been given a piece of code which is a physical model (filename 'agnsim.py') and some instructions to run it which I'm confused by.
The instructions say that I should import the code using

```
import agnsim as agn
```

and then to run the model with

```
ed = agn.Wilp(dens=3., incr=0.2, drac=2.0)
```

The argument above in Wilp will configure the run.

My question is, how do I actually run this?  Do I create a separate .py file that contains these two lines of code?

I've only ever run simple python programs before using e.g. >>>python file.py

Comment: *"Do I create a separate .py file that contains these two lines of code?"* - have you tried that? What happened? Are there further installation instructions? A `setup.py` file? You've not given much to go on.

Comment: OP, if my answer helped you, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

You should literally just open up the python console and type those two lines in.

```
$python
import agnsim as agn
ed = agn.Wilp(dens=3., incr=0.2, drac=2.0)
```

Make sure that `agnsim.py` is located at the same folder level from which you start python. E.g. If you're in "My Documents" and "agnsim.py" is in my documents, you should `cd` to "My Documents" and then start python there (from the command line).

Comment: That's one way, but it's rather cumbersome. He should install the package and write a two line script to run it.